# How to edit MS Word document file properties in Android?

Tags: android, ms-word

How can I edit Microsoft Word document file properties? (e.g. Title, Author, Subject, etc.)

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have been playing with the Office doc reader apps and found that they just let us rename the doc file name not properties. But I have seen into PowerAMP app, they let us edit the tags(e.g. Title, Artist, Album) of MP3 file which are similar to doc file properties. So, I am hoping that we may be able to edit properties for the word doc file too. I have looked around stackoverflow but didn't find anything for android yet.

Answer (score 0):

Bharat you should try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library .
This library supports to read, write and get the properties of all Microsoft Office Documents like doc ,ppt and xls files.
[Here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-read-write-excel-file-using.html) is an example how use it . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the new .docx format of Office >= 2007, you can do this by:

1. Rename .docx to .zip
2. Unpack the .zip file
3. Find the .xml file with the property definitions
4. Change them
5. Pack and rename the files again

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb266220%28v=office.12%29.aspx) out

Answer (score 0):

** Disclosure: I manage the docx4j project **

If you mean docx, you could try docx4j, which [runs on Android](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/).